# Doing notification controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new into rails and i have a question. I'm coding one Rails application for organize group attivity. I had realized a controller for Group Notification (when a new member was included into the group he/her recived one notification). I want to create a mechanism for notifications on new polls created. Do I need a new Controller or can i use the same?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want custom controllers, you certainly can.

However, I find they make things more confusing as they don't follow the standard structure and I often forget about them and why I made them.

---

I'd do my best to stick to the practice of having controllers that match my models.

Here's the way I would structure your app:

Models:

- Member (or maybe you call them users)
- Group
- Poll

Controllers:
*Used for things like create, show, list, update, delete a record*

- MembersController
- GroupController
- PollsController

When doing more than basic [CRUD](https://www.sumologic.com/glossary/crud/) operations, I focus on what is the "primary" or "parent" object and see if I can make it fit a CRUD operation.

So let's take your example of **adding a member to a group**:

If you have a form for a `member` where you can select an existing `group`, or maybe even create a new `group`, I would say `member` is the "primary" object and I would use the `MembersController#create` and `MembersController#update` actions. And I would use [`accepts_nested_attributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

```rb
class Member < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :groups
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :groups
end
```

If you have the opposite (a `group` form where you add or remove members), I would flip this, using `GroupsController#create` and `GroupsController#update` with nested attributes.

```rb
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :members
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :members
end
```

This way your routes are very standard:

```rb
resources :members

resources :groups

resources :polls
```

You can use this same logic for notifications of polls.

`Poll` would be the primary object, so you could handle this logic within the `PollsController#create` and `PollsController#update`

---

If you want to break away from the [RESTful routes](https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/c-and-net/basic-web-applications/introduction-to-restful-routing), I would still use these controllers.

E.g.:

```rb
# routes
resources :members do
  # the view with the form to choose a group
  get 'choose_group', on: :member
  # the controller action to receive the form data
  post 'add_to_group', on: :member 
end

# controller
class MembersController < ApplicationController
  def choose_group
    @member = Member.find(params[:id]
    @groups = Group.all
  end

  def add_to_group
    @member = Member.find(params[:id]
    @member.groups << Group.find(params[:group_id]
    if @member.save
      redirect_to 'some/other/place'
    else
      render 'choose_group'
    end
  end
end
```